Modern directions in Computational Algebraic Geometry
I've been having a good time working through Cox, Little, and O'Shea's Using Algebraic Geometry. In general I am interested in computational aspects of algebraic geometry. I am wondering what new big developments are out there in this area. I would greatly appreciate journals / conferences whose proceedings I can take a look at, as well as expository articles.
